# Windows Aero stopped working after NVIDIA Driver update

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce, aero

I updated Nvidia Driver from 306.97 to 337.88. Aero stopped working right after the installation was finished.

I have tried using Troubleshooting, re-running Windows Experience Index assessment, restarting DWM service, rolling back the driver, trying previous stable driver version 335.23 and installing 306.97 anew.

After each of these actions the Troubleshooter either does not detect a problem or says DWM is not running as well as color depth is too low. However, the depth is set to 32-bit and DWM service is running.

This is the result of Troubleshooter:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I get Windows Aero back up and running?

Comment: Have you tried System Restore to before you installed the update? That was a big jump in driver release. How about uninstalling all Nvidea drivers, reboot, then install the updated ones?

Comment: @CharlieRB 100% agreed

Comment: @CharlieRB I have tried removing and installing latest driver and I also installed latest windows updates. Nothing has changed apart from Troubleshooter no longer detects problems whatsoever.

I cannot do a System Restore because there has been no restoration points set up.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had a virtual video adapter installed that allowed me to use my tablet as an extension screen. I simply removed it from device manager and the problem was gone. Seems new driver messed with it somehow.